# Listing all the ecs clusters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to list all my ECS clusters.

Unfortunately, when i enter

```
aws ecs describe-clusters --cluster default --region us-east-1
```

I get the following error although I know that the clusters exist in the region::

```
{
    "clusters": [], 
    "failures": [
        {
            "reason": "MISSING", 
            "arn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:051582052996:cluster/default"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would love assistance in pointing out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `aws ecs list-clusters` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To list all the clusters use `aws ecs list-clusters`

Your command is failing because you are trying to describe (show) specific cluster called `default` which probably doesn't exist. You can see this from the given output that what is missing is cluster with this specific arn `arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:051582052996:cluster/default`